SQL Server Merge update only if different
I have a merge, correlating on a primary key, I want to insert when the id doesn't exist in target, delete if it doesn't exist in source, and update if fields on the record are different.
MERGE INTO mytable as [target]
USING (SELECT * FROM @Import) [source]
ON ([target].[id] = [source].[id])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN 
        INSERT ([Name], [Inserted]) 
        VALUES([source].[Name], SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())

WHEN MATCHED 
     AND (--not same or both null
          NOT ([target].[Name] = [source].[Name] OR ([target].[Name] IS NULL AND [source].[Name] IS NULL)) 
         )
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
        SET [target].[Name] = [source].[Name]
            [target].[Updated] = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

--this will also delete the records that I didn't want to update
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;

What I didn't realize is that if the match fails due to the name value being the same, then the delete will remove that record. I had originally thought that not matched logic was more based on the correlation in the USING and ON part of the merge statement. Is there a way to address this problem in the using statement, or should I move to an Insert, update, delete statement in an explicit transaction? I could probably add some conditions to the not matched logic, but it feels ugly because I have to duplicate the conditions in the match statement, but in their opposite form which seems error prone.

Is not using a MERGE an option?

Yes it is.  that was part of my question.  It originally seemed like using a MERGE was nicer syntactically, but then I came into this problem.  I just didn't want to go away from it without ensuring there I couldn't do what I needed to in a merge statement, cleanly.

Can you provide example data that demonstrates the issue? https://dbfiddle.uk/

That's not how it works, so no, what you seeing cannot happen because of that. But you have a classic error of thought here, because you want only rows that can be potentially deleted by the import to be DELETEd, not all rows not in the import, unless your import is a full snapshot

"if the match fails due to the name value being the same, then the delete will remove that record" this is factually incorrect. The delete will only happen if the  ON clause failed. Note that the WHEN MATCHED will fail if one OR both of them is null.

Because if only one is null, then the first = predicate evaluated to UNKNOWN and the second evaluates to FALSE, and UNKNOWN OR FALSE is UKNOWN and then NOT UNKNOWN is still UNKNOWN so it fails. Equally if both are null then you get UNKNOWN OR TRUE which is TRUE and then NOT TRUE is FALSE so it fails. Only if neither are null but are not equal is it going to work.
